# Magento 2 Show/Hide Minicart based on customer group

Tags: magento2, php, checkout

I want to show a minicart only for a specific customer group but I am unable to find the exact solution. If anyone knows please let me know. Thanks

Comment: could you share what have you done so far?

Comment: @Yousaf did you checked solution?

Comment: @RahulBarot Thanks, It worked for me

Comment: @Yousaf You're welcome! :)

Comment: Can you please answer on this question. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/336141/magento-2-how-to-change-attribute-filter-position-in-layered-navigation/336146#336146

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom module for it as below.

`Vendor/ExtendedMinicart/registration.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © DevAwesome All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_ExtendedMinicart', __DIR__);
```

`Vendor/ExtendedMinicart/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ExtendedMinicart">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Create system configuration to set customer group to which minicart is displayed

`Vendor/ExtendedMinicart/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="checkout" sortOrder="10" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" translate="label">
            <label>Checkout</label>
            <tab>sales</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_ExtendedMinicart::config_vendor_extendedminicart</resource>
            <group id="sidebar" sortOrder="10" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" translate="label">
                <label>Sidebar</label>
                <field id="minicart_display_customer_group" type="multiselect" sortOrder="10" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" translate="label">
                    <label>Display to Customer Group</label>
                    <comment>Minicart is only visible to selected customer groups</comment>
                    <source_model>Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Source\Group</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Create helper to get system configuration value

`Vendor/ExtendedMinicart/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Demo All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\ExtendedMinicart\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    /**
    * Minicart customer group display config path
    */
    const XML_PATH_MINICART_DISPLAY_CONFIG = 'checkout/sidebar/minicart_display_customer_group';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getMinicartDisplayConfig()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_MINICART_DISPLAY_CONFIG,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

Create preference to default block for minicart and add custom function to check minicart should be displayed or not

`Vendor/ExtendedMinicart/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" type="Vendor\ExtendedMinicart\Rewrite\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar"/>
</config>
```

`Vendor/ExtendedMinicart/Rewrite/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Demo All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\ExtendedMinicart\Rewrite\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;

class Sidebar extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar
{
    /**
     * Customer session
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\ExtendedMinicart\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $customHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customCustomerSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
     * @param \Magento\Customer\CustomerData\JsLayoutDataProviderPoolInterface $jsLayoutDataProvider
     * @param array $data
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json|null $serializer
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
        \Magento\Customer\CustomerData\JsLayoutDataProviderPoolInterface $jsLayoutDataProvider,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer = null,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Vendor\ExtendedMinicart\Helper\Data $customHelper
    ) {
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->customHelper = $customHelper;
        $this->customCustomerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $customerSession,
            $checkoutSession,
            $imageHelper,
            $jsLayoutDataProvider,
            $data,
            $serializer
        );
    }

    public function isMinicartCustomerGroupDisplay()
    {
        $enabledCustomerGroups = $this->customHelper->getMinicartDisplayConfig();
        $enabledCustomerGroups = explode(',', $enabledCustomerGroups);
        
        if(in_array(32000, $enabledCustomerGroups)){
            return true;
        }
        
        if($this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_AUTH)){
            $customerGroupId = $this->customCustomerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
        }else{
            $customerGroupId = 0;
        }
        
        if(in_array($customerGroupId, $enabledCustomerGroups)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Override default `minicart.phtml` in your custom module.

`Vendor/ExtendedMinicart/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ExtendedMinicart::cart/minicart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

`Vendor/ExtendedMinicart/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
?>
<?php $isVisible = $block->isMinicartCustomerGroupDisplay(); ?>
<?php if($isVisible): ?>
    <div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
        <a class="action showcart" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getShoppingCartUrl()) ?>"
           data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
            <span class="text"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('My Cart')) ?></span>
            <span class="counter qty empty"
                  data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false && !isLoading() },
                   blockLoader: isLoading">
                <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
                <span class="counter-label">
                <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                    <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
        <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):?>
            <div class="block block-minicart"
                 data-role="dropdownDialog"
                 data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                    "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                    "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                    "timeout": "2000",
                    "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                    "closeOnEscape": true,
                    "triggerClass":"active",
                    "parentClass":"active",
                    "buttons":[]}}'>
                <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                </div>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php $scriptString = <<<script
                require(['jquery'], function ($) {
                    $('a.action.showcart').click(function() {
                        $(document.body).trigger('processStart');
                    });
                });
    script;
            ?>
            <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false); ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], 'window.checkout = ' .
         /* @noEscape */ $block->getSerializedConfig(), false); ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-block='minicart']": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
            },
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= $block->escapeJs(
                    $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'))
                ) ?>"
            }
        }
        </script>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can download the complete module from [here](https://github.com/DevAwesomeK/extended-minicart) and try it on blank magento setup.

I hope it works for you. Thanks!