# Magento 2 How to change attribute filter position in layered navigation

Tags: magento2, product, php, layered-navigation

**I want to move the climate product attribute position from the bottom to the third position. Can you please help me out?**

[image]

Comment: please check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/55163/84221

Answer (score 0):

Check in Store -> Attributes Product.
The position attributed for single attribute is used for sorting attributes on layered navigation

Comment: Those sorting is not working for me

Answer (score -1):

Please use Sort Order after you login as admin in magento, this is optional parameter but it works while editing you need to give sort order values like 110, 220, 330 etc... then it will show in that order. 
Please play with it. This attached picture will clear everything.
[image]

Comment: I am asking about layered navigation filter.